# Different outcomes in tesseract invocation from OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, tesseract

I am using Tesseract OCR 3.04.01 with OpenCV 3.4.0 (python bindings) and despite using these identical versions on two Linux platforms and the same settings (oem, psmode, char_whitelist, and component_level), I keep getting significantly different outcomes. If I run the Tesseract OCR on this image:

[image: binarized image for tesseract]

on the first platform the result is

```
5Chh9id8lLorenz
```

and on the second

```
SchneiderLorenz
```

Ideally, I would like to get "Schneider, Lorenz". The image has been scaled up, binarized, and preprocessed before shown here but it is the same image in both cases (md5sum-ed) and it already works in a satisfactory manner in the second case.

I have searched everywhere for clues but no luck for now. The OpenCV code which acts differently on this same image is:

```
ocr = cv2.text.OCRTesseract_create("/tmp/data/tessdata",
                                   language="deu",
                                   char_whitelist="0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZäöüß,",
                                   oem=0,
                                   psmode=3)
output = ocr.run(text_img, text_img, 0, 0)
```

I would prefer to yield the same (hopefully good but still better also if bad) results on both platforms to consider such a solution deployable. Any help on this peculiarity is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:** The questions arising here are where should I look for further clues that could explain the differences. Isn't tesseract supposed to produce the same outcome if being the same version (and same leptonica version)? What else could influence the result besides all the parameters already provided to it above?

Comment: Try to change the language to `eng`, other than `deu`.

Comment: You mean the "deu" outcomes could be different? I am using the same tesseract data (also md5sum-ed) and the one for the 3.04 version. Also, some of the use cases involve fully German words.

Comment: I used `eng`, the result was ok.

Comment: The result is ok also with "deu" in the second case as I pointed above. And I have to stay to "deu" for the German cases. The question is how can I trace any reason for this since I need the same behavior everywhere. Let me update the question a bit.